# Is there an easy to use command line tool to create send transactions in Ethereum and forks of ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, sendtransaction, command-line

I'm trying to run a service that processes a bunch of ETH private keys and need to create send transactions via the command line. I know about geth, but are there other easier to use command line apps that just can pass in a private key, sender address, and amount as a parameter.

Metamask for command line would be nice as one can import a private key into the wallet and make transactions.

Answer (score 4):

The [eth-cli](https://github.com/protofire/eth-cli) project is what you are searching for.

This is a command-line tool that gives you some shortcut to do common tasks, and in particular, there is the `transaction:send` method that takes precisely the three parameters you have (private key, recipient, amount):

```
eth transaction:send --pk 3daa79a26454a5528a3523f9e6345efdbd636e63f8c24a835204e6ccb5c88f9e --to 0x828DaF877f46fdFB5F1239cd9cB8f0D6E1adfb80 --value 1000000000000000000
```

Please note that you need to connect to a node to send the transactions created this way.

Comment: what if I wanted to do a send from the polygon, avalanche, or BSC network?

Comment: I don't know Avalanche, but Polygon and BSC are EVM based so the only real difference should be the chainID (or networkID). You can use `network` command to add your custom network (https://github.com/protofire/eth-cli/blob/master/docs/COMMANDS.md#network) and then specity that when sending transactions.

Comment: whats the difference with eth-cli vs hardhat? Or what other ones do other people use?

Answer (score 1):

The dapp.tools has a command line tool called **seth**.
I can recommend a video by Mariano Conti on [how to set it up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hqx5yuskmRU):

You can send ether by running:

```
 seth send --value 0.1  to-address
```

In my opinion, the official documentation lacks a quickstart, but the Maker team has created a nice section [about the tool.](https://docs.makerdao.com/clis/seth)

You should also install [duppgrade](https://github.com/rari-capital/duppgrade) to take full advantage of the suite and join the [chat](https://dapphub.chat/)!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, JRPC is the only widely adopted way to interact with the blockchain.

The "easiest" would be to setup a default environment with something like hardhat, and writing a javascript script to do what you want.